# How to redirect live docker logs to a text file and display the logs on UI?

Tags: docker, logging, dockerfile, docker-machine, docker-registry

I want to redirect live logs of a running docker container to a text file so that I can display the live states on a UI.

Answer (score 0):

We can get the live logs using the below command.

```
$docker logs --follow my_test_container_name
or
$docker logs --follow my_test_container_id
```

if you want to redirect these logs then simply redirect to another file with ">" option.

Comment: Can we also stream the logs live to a UI instead of saving them on a text file?

Comment: Little bit a different advice, but you can use tmux, or simply use two terminal.  at one side you can follow logs by command above and then you can dump them to a file.